# How to extend a ListView WebPart (from code)

Tags: custom, list-view-web-part

I'd like to extend the ListView WebPart so that it can read data from the url... I tried to extend a ListView WebPart but compiler told me it is sealed and so I cannot extend.. Then I tried to insert a ListView WebPart INSIDE my custom webpart but this way doesn't work...

How could I do?

This is my code!

```
 using System;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using Microsoft.SharePoint;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace UrlParametrizedListViewWebPart.VisualWebPart1
{
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{

    private Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart myListView;
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site        
        string listName = "docs";
        SPWeb oWebSite = SPContext.Current.Web
        myListView = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart();
        myListView.Visible = true;
        myListView.EnableViewState = true;
        SPList list = oWebSite.Lists[listName];
        myListView.ListId = (System.Guid)list.ID;
        myListView.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.IT.ToString();

        Controls.Add(myListView);
        }
}
}
```

Result of this code:

< !-- #RENDER FAILED -->

I tried another way: add all the controls of the "son webpart" and not the webpart.. It seems working!
I think is not the right way to do that.. So if everybody has some suggestion... =)

```
namespace UrlParametrizedListViewWebPart.VisualWebPart1
{
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{

    private Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart myListView;
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site        
        string listName = "docs";
        SPWeb oWebSite = SPContext.Current.Web
        myListView = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart();
        myListView.Visible = true;
        myListView.EnableViewState = true;
        SPList list = oWebSite.Lists[listName];
        myListView.ListId = (System.Guid)list.ID;
        myListView.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.IT.ToString();
        //ADDS MANUALLY THE WP CONTROLS:
        foreach(Control c in myListView.Controls)
        {
             this.Controls.Add(c);
        }

        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that you must not dispose the SPContext.Current.Site and the SPContext.Current.Web as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx. But this will probably not solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know really HOW, but this code works!

Take a look =)

```
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{
    private Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart myListView;
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        string listName = "docs";
        SPWeb oWebSite = SPContext.Current.Web;
        myListView = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart();
        myListView.Visible = true;
        myListView.EnableViewState = true;
        SPList list = oWebSite.Lists[listName];

        myListView.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        myListView.TitleUrl = list.DefaultViewUrl;
        myListView.WebId = list.ParentWeb.ID;

        myListView.ListId = (System.Guid)list.ID;
        myListView.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();

        myListView.HelpMode = WebPartHelpMode.Modeless;

        Controls.Add(myListView);
    }
```

Now, to access the params simply use the Request.params and put in list name the list name that you want.. I create this cose (it's incomplete) to select the folder and the document library from URL in the webpart!

Hope this will help someone =)

Answer (score 2):

`myListView.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();` did the trick for you...

If you set the ViewGuid property, it needs the Guid of the particular View Case sensitive!