# SharePoint Data Control to show Custom Data Source

Tags: 2010, web-part, spsitedataquery

I am building a custom visual webpart where I want to show all the calendar events across a site using SPSiteDataQuery. I know I can use asp.net repeater or grid view to show the data but I was wondering if there is a SharePoint data control I can leverage to have all the functionalities a list view webpart has (ecb/context menu, sorting, paging, etc). Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx), its just like List View...

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx), its just like List View...

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16 is a good resource for SPGridView

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate a `ListViewWebPart` in a visual web part.

Here's an example posted on this site:

[How to extend a ListView WebPart (from code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24476/how-to-extend-a-listview-webpart-from-code)

And here's a blog post with examples on how to perform the second option:

[Create Custom ListViewWebPart](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/08/create-custom-listviewwebpart.html)

Comment: +1, sadly, `ListViewWebPart` is sealed. However both links are great and I can recommend them.

Comment: Reflection my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I see there's a `ListViewByQuery` Web Part [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.aspx). I'll be trying it out to see if it does what I need.